# How do I unlock of login the local console from SSH

Tags: login, 22.04, session, gnome-session

I would like to remotely unlock and/or log into the local console from SSH. The reason I want this is to unlock the machine for my son so he can play games.

I want it to behave as if he'd typed in my password at the login or unlock prompt.

Is there a way to force Gnome to unlock (if it's locked), or to force a local console login while remotely SSH'd into the machine? It seems that if something happens when you type your password correctly at the login prompt, you should be able to cause that same thing to happen from an SSH shell somehow, even if you need `sudo` to do so.

Comment: It might be simpler to provide your son his own user account so he can type in his own password.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that, but he's of the age that I want to know every time he's allowed to log in.
Also, I know quite a bit about Linux, and I was curious how this worked. But had no idea how to even crack it researching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unlock with `loginctl unlock-sessions` or `sudo loginctl unlock-sessions`